# как сделать парсер онлайна на сервере и вставить его в html шаблон django?

Tags: python, html, django

Вообщем мне нужно спарсить количество онлайна на сервере с сайта, как сделать обычный парсер я знаю, но как сделать так что бы отобразить значение в html шаблоне нет
Предполагаю что можно сделать через базу данных,из парсера сохранять значение в базу данных и потом в html считывать эту бд и вставлять, но можно ли как то сделать разумнее?

Answer (score 0):

Суть задачи не совсем ясна. Предположу что у вас есть: сайт, парсер и второй сайт с которого парсите данные. Тогда можно реализовать такой сценарий. В django есть удобный механизм для запуска автономных сценариев [management-commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/). Такие сценарии можно инициировать в [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/). Опишите в нем ваш парсер, результат складывайте в бд, ну а далее используйте данные как вам необходимо. Так достаточно удобно контролировать поток данных с разных источников в своей django.